# Laravel updating related models and tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For example, I have this block of code.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $abc = Model::find($id);
    $abc->column1 = $request->input1;
    $abc->column2 = $request->input2;
    $abc->save();
}
```

On save of the $abc object, I have to update a related model. That goes like this.

Note: $abc hasMany $def;

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $abc = Model::find($id);
    $abc->column1 = $request->input1;
    $abc->column2 = $request->input2;
    $abc->save();

    if($abc){
        foreach($request->data){
             //what should I do here to update the rows in the table that 
               has the same $abc->id as above ?

        }
    }
}
```

I have seen associate(), $abc->def()->save($abc), but can't think of a way on how to properly save the array of data to the related table.

---

Comment: please add more details .. what is the table that you are using? datatable yajra or something else? where is your blade code? and to understand further are you trying to mass update or show data or both?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $abc = Model::find($id);

    if(isset($abc)){

        $abc->column1 = $request->input1;
        $abc->column2 = $request->input2;
        $abc->save();

        // assuming the related model is called xyz
        if($abc->xyz !== null) {
           $abc->xyz->column3 = $request->input3;
           $abc->xyz->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course there are more elegant ways of dealing with relationships, depending on the solution you are working on.